# Replacing an IN() subquery by an equivalent EXISTS() query

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

Given two simple tables in MySQL database.

- product (having attributes, prod_id, prod_name ...)
- product_image (having attributes, product_image_id, prod_id (references prod_id in the product table), prod_image ...)

The relationship between these tables in intuitive - one to many from `product` to `product_image`.

---

I need to retrieve a result set (only `prod_image`) from the `product_image` table having maximum `product_image_id` in **each group of products**.

The following query does exactly that.

```
SELECT p.prod_image
FROM   product_image p 
WHERE  p.product_image_id IN(SELECT max(pp.product_image_id) 
                             FROM   product_image pp 
                             GROUP  BY pp.prod_id)
```

How can this query be rewritten using `EXISTS()`?

Comment: Are you sure the posted query returns what you need ? Subquery in `IN` as it is returns distinct values of `prod_id`...

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET - or is EXISTS a specific part of the assignment?

Comment: `IN()` queries (like this) are not properly generated in an ORM. Therefore, I'm looking for an alternative (joins are not always alternatives). There is no assignment.

Comment: @a1ex07 : Sorry, there was a mistake in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query follows the logic of your question, which is to get the maximum `prod_image_id` for each `prod_id`.

```
SELECT p1.prod_image 
FROM   product_image p1 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                  FROM   product_image p2 
                  WHERE  p1.prod_id = p2.prod_id 
                         AND p1.product_image_id < p2.product_image_id)
```